# Ubuntu server rename - can not resolve host

Tags: ubuntu

I renamed an Ubuntu 14.04 server (changed name in hostname) and now when I sudo I get a can not resolve host {nane} message.  The command still works though.  Do I need to change another file to bind the name to the loopback interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sudo shouldn't care about the hostname of the machine unless it is specified in the /etc/sudoers file.  But if it were wrong there you wouldnlt be able to use sudo.  If you just want to get rid of the error edit your /etc/hosts and add `127.0.0.1 newhostname.yourdomain newhostname` then your machine will be able to resolve that hostname.